# Slow performance android project

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity

Please I'm facing an issue in my android project, and am still intermediate level. 
I download plugin tool to find the bugs. it is called (FindBugs). and now it is pointing me to performance problem which is actually what I'm suffering from. 
My app has to receive data as digital (ADC 10bit from PIC controller) using Bluetooth. All worked fine except that it is taking too much time to execute and draw the graph for the digital data. 
The FindBugs tool is pointing to:
String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

and it says it would cause the application behaviour to vary between platforms. 
Can anybody could help me with that? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TraceView (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html)
for finding the thread and method which slows down your app.